# how to create android application layout with multiple screen supports?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my xml file. i am new to android development.  I need to know how can i modified this layout into responsive for multiple screen sizes of the phones? I have created directories as layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge. but it is not working properly. I used sp for textviews and dp for other widgets. That is also not working. Please help me to modify this xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        tools:context="com.respectcab.app.MainActivity"
        tools:openDrawer="start"
        tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light" />


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText"><![CDATA[
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        ]]>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/driver"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logout"
            android:text="Start Trip"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cus_mobile"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Logout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cus_mobile"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driver_id_main"
            android:layout_width="91sp"
            android:layout_height="55sp"

            android:layout_below="@+id/driver_mobile"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="33sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="231sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="461sp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cus_email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/driver_total_earn"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.44"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/driver_mobile"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.765"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driver_total_earn"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="44sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/driver_mobile"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="65sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="65sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="461sp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/driver_id_main"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/driver_id_main"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cus_email"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cus_mobile"
            android:layout_width="398dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cus_email"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:hint="Customer Mobile No"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cus_email"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cus_email"
            android:layout_width="404dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
            android:hint="Customer Email"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_package"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="115dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="130dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_user_profile"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.407"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driver_name"
            android:layout_width="312sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driver_mobile"
            android:layout_width="177sp"
            android:layout_height="33sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/driver_name"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="124sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="124sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="147sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="147sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.492"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/driver_name" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/driver_mobile"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:scaleX="2.5"
            android:scaleY="2.5"
            android:textOff="Turn On"
            android:textOn="Turn Off"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.472"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/driver_mobile"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Click Here to Enable Disable GPS location service!"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.958"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="248sp"
            android:layout_height="37sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="location service Stauts Shows Here"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="326dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="142dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <!--<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/vehicle_list_name"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="636dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="218dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_alignParentStart="true"-->
            <!--android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"-->
            <!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"-->
            <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
            <!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->
            <!--tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"-->
            <!--tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-35dp"-->
            <!--tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp"-->
            <!--tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item" />-->

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_package"
            android:layout_width="307dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.636"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch1" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: **multiple screen sizes** - Mobile and tablet? or only mobile?

Comment: @sanjeev all the mobile devices.

Comment: just design in one layout and use preview to check for various screen sizes. You don't need to design separately.

Comment: But the thing is, when we set this layout as content layout, it support only one screen size. If we use another small or larger screen phone layout widgets are not adjust automatically. Some of the widget are not showing, some of are too many small or large etc. there are many issues if I install app into another application.

Comment: Deeptha I just checked your code and please use `wrap_content` or `match_parent` and never hardcode in dp to views unless really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this library for layout so all size screen might be cover with one layout:) - implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

[link](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Comment: Thanks man. Above xml code works fine. But another xml code I have changed, it was not working properly. I used sdp for textview also . Is that a problem?

Comment: @DeepthaNandapala

for text use ssp and for view use sdp:)
https://github.com/intuit/ssp

Comment: I have tried. But the result is same. in preview window I had changed the screen sizes and checked. It was not working.

Comment: using of ssp and sdp the result is better then the dp and sp